# How to get Excel to Have Word Convert PDF to Text?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

I am running the code below, in Excel, and it works fine, on my personal laptop, to convert a PDF file to a text file.

```
Sub ConvertPDFtoTextViaWord()
   Const filePath As String = "C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\"
   Dim file As String, fileName As String
   Dim myWord As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document
   Set myWord = New Word.Application
   file = Dir(filePath & "*.pdf")
   myWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
   Do While file <> ""
       fileName = Replace(file, "pdf", "txt")
       Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(fileName:=filePath & file, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")
       myDoc.SaveAs2 filePath & fileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText, Encoding:=1252, lineending:=wdCRLF
       myDoc.Close True
       file = Dir
   Loop
   Set myDoc = Nothing
   Set myWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when I run the same code on my office laptop, it stops on this line:

```
myDoc.SaveAs2 filePath & fileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText, Encoding:=1252, lineending:=wdCRLF
```

When I get to this line on my office laptop, I get this error:

```
Run time error 91: object variable or with block not set.
```

Maybe the `Set myDoc` command is not being set correctly. When I mouse-over myDoc, I see `myDoc = Nothing`. myDoc SHOULD be the PDF file, but it's not. What's happening here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check that the `filename` parameter is set to a pdf file that exists in that location. I've been surprised that Word sometimes does not throw an error if a file is missing, but just returns `Nothing`. Also, remove the `myWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` line while debugging as you could be hiding a meaningful error message. Also might any of the filenames have the text 'pdf' in them other than at the end?

Comment: I had to change this line: Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(fileName:=filePath & file, ReadOnly:=True, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")

Now it works fine.